# Include matter in makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, freertos, openocd

in the makefile there is written:

```
# Include the dependency files
-include $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/*.d)
```

and through the cmd windows it say:

```
E:\A_1_Projekt>make clean
makefile:394: no file name for `-include'
Cleaning project:
rm -rf obj
rm -rf docs/html
```

So my question is, what does this line means ( no file name for `-include')  and how can i fix this?

Comment: It means there are no files in `$(OBJDIR)` that end with `.d`... The `-` at the beginning of the line means that this is not a fatal error.

Comment: The `-` sign should also suppress the warning...  Which version of make?

Comment: Which version of make? I truly don't know, this is because i happen to make internship, the other has download this for me, and i don't know which version.